# Hosting git projects on my own website

Tags: git, github, gitorious

I want something similar to GitHub but on my own website.

Something like Gitorious/WebGit/GitList, but PHP based (requirement).

Maybe something like google code? I need it to work with Git repositories.

Answer (score 4):

If you can go around your language requirement and go with Ruby, you should have a look at [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/), which is a GitHub clone that you can host by yourself.
[Here is a tutorial](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/04/21/tutorial-setting-up-gitlab-on-debian-6/) that explains how to install it on Debian 6.

If you are tied to PHP, there are IMHO very little possibilities but you should have a look at these projects:

- [GitPHP](http://www.gitphp.org/projects/gitphp/wiki)
- [mtrack](http://mtrack.wezfurlong.org/)
- [traq.io](http://traq.io/)

**EDIT:** an other possibility that I didn't spot initially is [GitList](http://gitlist.org/)

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to install ruby/ruby on rails. I've tried more than one tutorial, without any success. I'm running Debian 6

Comment: @AhmedHamdy Did you check the other 3 projects? The 3 of them are PHP based... HTH

Comment: I did check em, GitPHP doesn't have an issue tracker. mtrack is ugly and doesn't have what I need. traq is the closest to what I need but only has SVN. I require Git.

Comment: @AhmedHamdy Just updated my answer to add a link to a tutorial... HTH

Comment: That's damn complicated. Anyway, I like traq, just that it supports SVN only. Is there any alternative that support Git?

Comment: If you look at the _traq_ source code, you can see [here](https://github.com/nirix/traq/tree/master/system/libraries/scm/adapters) that there is a Git adapter. You should try this...

Comment: Traq has tons of bugs, from menu disappearing to login problems. Any alternatives? I want something that users can use without having to login. I could even forget about issue tracking.